# Export AMCharts content to one pdf in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, dojo, amcharts

I am stuck with the approach for exporting content which is in charts format, charts are not in the image format by the way. These charts will be generating in the runtime.

**Flow is like this:**

1) All charts use ajax calls or $.getJson method to hit the APIs and get the data from APIs.

2) After getting data, responsive charts will be coming using data from the APIs.

3) All these charts are present in one dashboard with separate tabs for different category charts like weather, area per sq ft etc.

**Problem:**

1) I used backend functionality to generate XLS format using python which contains data for all of these charts and on one click I am able to download XLS.

2) I cannot do this objective using backend because all of the charts content are drawn in the frontend.

3) I followed one approach which I feel the code is redundant, again I am hitting all the APIs, generating one HTML content and exporting that in one pdf using browser's inbuilt functionality i.e 'Save as PDF'.

4) But what I want is on one click all the contents of charts should be downloaded as PDF to respective users.

**Note:**

- Complete JS chart's code is in Dojo framework.
- AMCharts provide PDF functionality at an each individual chart level but I want to export all the charts.

Doubts:
Any library to extract the HTML content to pdf in JS or Jquery?

Any help on the approach is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.amcharts it can render multiple charts

Comment: AmCharts use [PDFMake](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) for the export feature. You could capture individual images for each chart and then putting them together using PDFMake's content object.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, what @KevinBrown Brown mentioned looks great to me.

Comment: Thanks @Darlesson, will look into it.